# Get all repositories of two package types via Artifactory API

Tags: artifactory

I'm trying to get all repositories of two package types (Maven and Terraform). The URL I'm trying is:

```
curl -u username:password -X GET "https://artifactory.es/artifactory/api/repositories?packageType=docker,helm"
```

But I'm getting only the packages of the first one, in this case Docker packages.

Comment: As described in the official docs (https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-GetRepositories), you can only get one repo type at a time. Although this would be a nice addition.

Comment: You can also just pull out all repositories into a big json output and clean it up with `jq` or similar

Comment: I added these comments as an official answer with a working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the official docs ([The GetRepositories API](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-GetRepositories)), you can only get one repo type at a time. Although this would be a nice addition.

You can use a tool like `jq` and simply manipulate data from a full list of all repositories.

```
curl -u username:password -X GET "https://artifactory.es/artifactory/api/repositories" | jq '[.[] | select (.packageType == "Docker" or .packageType == "Helm")]'
```

This will leave you with the **Docker** or **Helm** repositories only.